# Why there is a VBA-SAP Script Run-Time Error: 619 when value is assigned through a variable

Tags: vba, scripting, sap-gui

Have a peculiar problem.

The system throws a 619 run-time error when I use the following code with a variable `X="5600026953"`.

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRM06E-EVRTN").Text = X
```

but it process when the value is assigned directly.

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRM06E-EVRTN").Text = "5600026953"
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Probably you did not analyze enough because the error 619 means the ID was not found in the screen, and assigning a value through variable instead of literal cannot produce this error.

Comment: What happens if you convert the variable X as a string? e.g. ... = cstr(X)